# Preserve arrangement of Preview tabs and windows on restart

Tags: windows, pdf, preview, restart, tabs

To keep organized, I generally open closely-related PDF files as tabs in the same Preview window, with a separate multi-tab window for each distinct subject (so about 4 or 5 windows, with 5 tabs open in each window). When I close and re-open Preview, or when I restart my laptop, the windows open up as independent, single-tab windows instead of keeping the previous tab arrangement. This is at odds with every other app I use that has a "tabs" feature (e.g. Safari, Chrome, Skim, iTerm). It's the most frustrating part of every restart.

Is there any way to get Preview to remember and preserve my tab arrangements?

**Edit**: I am on macOS Ventura 13.5, Preview preferences for "When opening files" are set to "Open groups of files in the same window", and system settings "Prefer tabs when opening documents" is set to "Never". I guess it could be that last setting but does not seem to affect any other apps. Hoping someone can help.

Comment: What do you have set in Preview's Preferences > Images "When opening files"?

Comment: @benwiggy "Open groups of files in the same window"